# onClick does not find its method

Tags: java, android

When I click a button, its method does not get called, but exception is thrown. Why?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: myMethod [class android.view.View]
```

main.xml:

```
android:onClick="myMethod"
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
//onCreate etc

    public void myMethod() {
    }
}
```

Comment: @duffymo Heh; was just doing the same thing ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 public void myMethod(View view) {

    }
```

you forgot parameter `View` of `myMethod`

And if you have no view then you can call method `myMethod(null)`

Comment: So how would I then call myMethod "manually"? Eg if I want to execute this method within my business logic where I do not have a View, and not also want it to catch on button clicks (where it needs the view)?

Comment: If you don't use the view parameter, just do myMethod(null);